# Redux-saga wait and combine multiple action

Tags: react-native, redux, redux-saga

I am implementing a log system, when scroll down a list a lot of LIST_ITEM_SHOWN action would be dispatched. Then Saga will call the API to send out the log.

I want to make it wait for e.g. 2 second until no further LIST_ITEM_SHOWN is dispatched, and group the LIST_ITEM_SHOWN actions to one to reduce API call.

Can this be done in Saga level? or can only be managed in component/container level?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah, it's pretty easy to implement in saga:

```
yield takeLatest('LIST_ITEM_SHOWN', watchListItemShown);
```

so, taking latest `LIST_ITEM_SHOWN` action to store to logs, so in case of multiple actions - the previous tasks are cancelled (won't go after `delay`).

```
// for simplicity storing logs in private variable, consider using redux or something similar
let logs = []; 
function* watchListItemShown(action) {
  yield call(logs.push, action.payload);
  yield call(delay, 2000); 
  yield call(saveToApi, logs);
  logs = []; 
}
```

So on every `LIST_ITEM_SHOWN` action you store logs into local variable (you can consider using `redux` or something similar instead, so you'll do better logs management via reducers). And after 2 seconds delay the actual save is called.